# Why am I not able to change the theme of my app to HOLO.DARK?

Tags: android

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Zine"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" >

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        android:label="@string/Zine" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>









    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

this is my Androidmanifest.xml

Now this is the app screen:
[image]

I have selected the holo dark theme yet I am not getting black color on screen. Instead, I am getting the default theme. How do I fix this?

Comment: From which theme is your AppTheme inheriting? Probably not from Holo.Dark... Anyway you should use the Material theme of the support library. You still can make it look dark or use the DayNight theme but it also takes care of a lot of styling for you.

Comment: Here you are use only  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

and in your style.xml

<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>

Answer (score 0):

Do this In your Code.. Working Fine

Also Your Error Reason

**The reason you are having this problem is because you are extending the  activity with you are trying to apply the dialog theme to is extending AppCompatActivity which requires the AppCompat theme to be applied.**

**Change the Java inheritance from AppCompatActivity to Activity and leave the dialog theme in the manifest as it is.**

**Set in Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="Zine"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
    android:label="@string/Zine" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</activity>
```

**In You styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->

<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: did it but now its showing "unfortunately zine has stopped"

Comment: Clean The project and rebulid again

Comment: `<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
`

Comment: Your MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity or Activity?

Comment: i have two activities splash screen and main activity whereas spalsh screen is a launcher activity and it extends "Activity" 
where as main activity extends "AppCompatActivity"

Comment: Give to both Extends with Activity... And Check now Clean also project